# Time Machine Network Backup via FTP

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I have two Macs, a G5 tower and a Macbook Pro. I want to backup the Macbook Pro to an external hard drive on the G5 tower via Time Machine.

I know there is a way to do this; my friend has his setup exactly like I want it.

I tried FTP sharing the backup drive on the G5 and trying to connect to it on the Macbook Pro. The G5 is running 10.5.8 and the Macbook Pro 10.6.8.

Comment: FTP will not work, you're going to have to use AFP to share the Time Machine volume.

Comment: Well...that would be why...

Comment: In *Sharing* - *File Sharing* preferences, under "Options", just enable it [like that](http://i.imgur.com/pEvhA.png). You can also check out [this video tutorial](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/02/22/ask-tuaw-video-edition-time-machine-over-a-network/)

Comment: Yes it did work.

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to connect the external hard drive directly to the MBP?

Comment: @Lèsemajesté Yes, but it's a laptop that isn't regularly in a certain location, so it's easier to just backup via a network.

Comment: I see. I thought you meant you were trying to FTP over your local WiFi or something while you were at home.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté No, I that at home, the laptop isn't regularly in one place, which doesn't allow me to plug it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharing a Time Machine volume over the network only works reliably with Apple Filing Protocol (AFP). If you use Leopard (10.5.8) or later, that should be no problem. On earlier versions, some hacking is required.

Share your drive over *Sharing Preferences* → *File Sharing*. Under "Options", enable AFP sharing.

[image]

There's also a [video tutorial](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/02/22/ask-tuaw-video-edition-time-machine-over-a-network/) on the very same subject.